# Closing drop-down menu by clicking on the button itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've seen a lot of questions on this wesite about closing a drop-down menu by clicking anywhere on the page.

My question is a little bit different though. I don't want the dropdown-menu to close by clicking outside of it. The moment I click on the button that shows me the menu, I want the menu to stay like that (drop-downed) untill the user clicks on that same button again. Also, the moment when the menu is shown, I want it to push the other elements direcly beneath it down. These elements could be for example other buttons. You guys might have seen this concept on some websites and I like the idea. I want to create the same thing, but I don't how.

This will probably be made with Javascript since this is easier, but I don't know how to do it. Do you guys have any ideas or tips?

I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's an example of what I ment: `Link to jsfiddle ->`https://jsfiddle.net/Cerebrl/uhykY/

I want to push down button 2 and 3 the moment the first menu is drop downed, so it can create it's own space to display. And secondly, the menu should only close the moment I push the button, not by clicking outside of it.

Comment: can you post some code or a fiddle?

Comment: I don't have any specific code right now. It's more of a concept. But I can try to make a bit of code to be more specific. Hold on.

Comment: Alright, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Cerebrl/uhykY/

As you can see, I only gave drop-down functionality to the first button. But there are two things I'd like to see differently. 1. At the moment the menu drops down, I want it to push the other two buttons down to create it's own space to display. 2.The menu should ONLY close when I push the first button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can use toggleSlide method in two lines like

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('ul').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  background: none #FA982E;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}
ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button data-toggle="#menu-main" title="Click to toggle">Toggle Menu</button>
</p>
<ul id="menu-main">
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the menu to push the content below, than put it in normal flow. What you need is a simple jQuery's [slideToggle method](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and to hide the menu by default:

```js
$('[data-toggle]').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault;
    var thisLink = $(this);
    var toToggle = $( thisLink.data('toggle') );
    toToggle.slideToggle(200);
})
```

```css
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.toggle-menu a {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: none #F1B475;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu-main {
    background: none #FA982E;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}
#menu-main a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu-main a:hover,
#menu-main a:focus {
    background: none #D0812D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-menu">
    <p>
        HALLO
        <a data-toggle="#menu-main" title="Click to toggle">+</a>
    </p>
    
</div>
<ul id="menu-main">
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
</ul>
<p>
    Other content
</p>
```

Since the menu has no absolute or fixed position, it will push the content below it. **[JSFiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/aqfyLgco/)**

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I meant and what I'm trying to create. This was really helpfull. Thank you so much!